# How to decompile an Android .apk file?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, apk, decompiling

i would like to decompile on my MAC OS X, an Android .apk file. It's possible but i have some difficulties. JD GUI is down.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont always need JD-GUI, there are several options to do so, I personally use DED, it comes with a script that you can run. It uses jasmin-classes and soot, which helps in making the class files more efficient. Use APKtool to get the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Some apks can be decompiled by just renaming them to .zip for example app-debug.apk once renamed to app-debug.zip can be unzipped.